# How to call a js function within html file in symfony / encore?

Tags: javascript, symfony, frontend, twig

I would like to call a function within a built js file in my symfony project.

```js
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="doThis(this, {{ value_from_twig }})">Clickme</button>
```

But the function can't be found, even if I included it correctly:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('tag') }}
```

I have marked the function to export. I have also tried to import the neccecary files within an other script tag, but this did not work.

Comment: Can you verify that your script gets inserted before the button? what if you enter `doThis` into browser console, is it defined?

Comment: No it is not defined when I enter doThis in the browser console. How can I verify, that the button is loaded after the script?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Symfony or Twig? Would this work properly if both were not involved, when you use static markup?

Comment: @chu then you should inspect the script, your function `doThis` seems not to be a direct member of window, how do you define it?